# want to access latest instagram feeds in website, but not getting any response from instagram

Tags: php, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

**want to access latest instagram feeds in website, but not getting any response from instagram**

I have created client with my instagram developers a/c.. but its at sandbox mode..

when I try to submit it for review.. instagram mentioning "you can access latest 20 feeds with sandbox a/c also"

I **tried with multiple instagram urls but not getting any response**

Tried Urls:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=XYZ
```

(No Response)

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/user_name/media/recent?client_id=XYZ
```

(No Response)

```
https://www.instagram.com/user_name/?__a=1
```

(No Response)

```
https://www.instagram.com/user_name/media/
```

(No Response)

**I think instagram changes url structure.. please help me to integrate latest instagram posts with website**

Comment: Have you tried `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`?

Comment: yes.. but not done

Comment: Where are you testing the api? Postman?

Comment: @AakashTushar testing it on live server

Comment: Can try it in postman and see what response code are you receiving?